# How to get systemd-udevd to create a bridge device at start up?

Tags: networking, systemd, bridge

I am running Ubuntu server 15.04 in a virtual machine. I am able to use the `brctl` program to create and manipulate networking bridges. I've decided to persist the setup (through reboots) by updating my `/etc/network/interfaces` as shown below:

```
auto m-br0
iface m-br0 inet static
bridge_stp 0ff
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 10.0.0.1
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

However, when the VM comes back up, the bridge is not there. Checking `journalctl` shows the following:

```
Jul 21 20:44:16 Net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
Jul 21 20:44:16 Net networking[381]: * Configuring network interfaces...
Jul 21 20:44:16 Net networking[381]: Cannot find device "m-br0"
Jul 21 20:44:16 Net networking[381]: Failed to bring up m-br0.
Jul 21 20:44:16 Net networking[381]: ...done.
Jul 21 20:44:16 Net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Raise network interfaces...
```

I was hoping that the bridge creation would be done by the underlying framework being leveraged by `brctl` since, I was able to do all the bridge creation and configuration with it. But, I do not think that this facility (i.e. `systemd-udevd`) is being invoked and can't figure out how to get it to create a device for my bridge. Should I create `.device` unit file for my bridge and where in the start-up process should I put it? (I cannot find a sample `.device` unit file on my system to give me an idea on how to go about)

Would someone have some pointers for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bridge creation with `ifupdown`, you should usually specify the underlying device using `bridge_ports`.  And what is `bridge_stp 0ff`???

Working configuration would be like:

```
auto m-br0
iface m-br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 10.0.0.1
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

Read [bridge-utils-interfaces manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html) for detail.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. `0ff` was a typo :) Sorry for confusing you. I read the man page you referenced and it appears that bridge_ports is a mandatory property in `/etc/network/interfaces`. I do not want to create connection to those ports yet. I would have to find another way to get the bridge created.

Comment: @PieruPoika Then you could use `bridge_ports none`, or something like `pre-up brctl addbr m-br0`.

Comment: @PieruPoika One more thing, you should specify `netmask` for `inet static` interface, otherwise it might be set to `255.0.0.0`  which would be unwanted configuration.  Actually you don't necessarily have to specify `network` and `broadcast` while you should always specify `address` and `netmask` there.

Comment: Just to confirm @yaegashi suggestion that in my case the setting `bridge-ports none` did the trick